# How to store file in an array

Tags: bash, files, array

How can I store contents of a file in array, for example:

my file has :

```
a /n
b /n
c /n
d /n
```

I want to store each line in array, how can I?

I'm using bash 3 on OSX.

Comment: `mapfile -t array <file`

Comment: @Costas i am getting mapfile command not found error

Comment: @Mathew `mapfile` requires bash version 4.0 or better.  What OS are you on? OSX?

Comment: yes i am on OSX, but can you tell me a less recent way to doing this array storage because, I will need to run this script is older versions as well

Comment: Do you have `readlines` command?

Comment: no i have `read` though

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 1):

```
while IFS= read -r line
do
    array[${#array[*]}]="$line"
done <file
```

Comment: can i loop through the elements by: for test in "${array[@]}" ?

Comment: You are free to try. Why do you ask for permission?